# React Native on iOS: Image component not rendering an image from a specific URI

Tags: react-native

```
<Image
  style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
  source={{ uri: 'https://api.openpay.mx/barcode/185017437691737?width=1&height=100' }}
/>
```

I would expect the code above to render an image on screen. It does not. If I go to that link in a browser or curl it from the terminal it renders or downloads as expected. But React Native on iOS does *not* render it even though it works on Android and Web.

See the example [here](https://snack.expo.io/QH4nUBfc6).

Answer (score 1):

Pasting in your code into the example on the [react native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image) rendered the image correctly for me. This could be a problem with a container or internet connectivity, but without the rest of the code it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Using that docs link you cited, it rendered correctly on Web and Android but not on iOS, which is the platform I'm working on. That's a good catch though, I will update the question to specify.